# How to update data with image using AngularJS $http.put Method

Tags: angularjs

I am created a Laravel application to upload data with image.I am successfully done this task using following way in AngularJs

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
 };
}]);



app.controller('rowController', function($scope,$http,$modal,Row){
       $scope.saveItem=function(){
             var fd = new FormData();
        //fd.append('photo', $scope.myFile);

        for(var key in $scope.newrow)
            fd.append(key,$scope.newrow[key]);

        $http.post('/api/row_material', fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
            .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                console.log(data);
            }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
                console.log(data);
            });
       }
  }
```

Above POST method successfully worked for me.Now I need to update data with image using $http.put() method.I am created a method as listed below;

```
$scope.updateItem=function(){
        var fd = new FormData();

        for(var key in $scope.newrow)
            fd.append(key,$scope.newrow[key]);
        var uri='api/row_material/1';
         $http.put(uri,fd,{headers: '{"Content-Type": undefined}'} )
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert('Updated Successfully.');
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                alert('Server error');
                console.log(data);
            });
}
```

But above put method causes an error given below;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
       <style>
        /* Copyright (c) 2010, Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved. Code licensed under the BSD License: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/license.html */
        html{color:#000;background:#FFF;}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}fieldset,img{border:0;}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}li{list-style:none;}caption,th{text-align:left;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}q:before,q:after{content:'';}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal;}sup{vertical-align:text-top;}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom;}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}input,textarea,select{*font-size:100%;}legend{color:#000;}
        html { background: #eee[…]
```

Above put method work with out using FormDate() using following way.But Image not uploaded to server

```
$scope.updateItem=function(){


        var uri='api/row_material/1';
         $http.put(uri,$scope.newrow,{headers: '{"Content-Type": undefined}'} )
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert('Updated Successfully.');
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                alert('Server error');
                console.log(data);
            });
}
```

I need your help to update data with image using FormData put method in AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use ng file upload plugin. I'm not sure what you are using on the backend but this plugin will help you to send file that is selected from input tag with your data. Check all their demo to get a clear idea.

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several good approaches for this..

One of them is the one given below..

```css
     var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
          
             myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
                return {
                   restrict: 'A',
                   link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                      var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                      var modelSetter = model.assign;
                      
                      element.bind('change', function(){
                         scope.$apply(function(){
                            modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                         });
                      });
                   }
                };
             }]);
          
             myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
                this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
                   var fd = new FormData();
                   fd.append('file', file);
                
                   $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                      transformRequest: angular.identity,
                      headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
                   })
                
                   .success(function(){
                   })
                
                   .error(function(){
                   });
                }
             }]);
          
             myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){
                $scope.uploadFile = function(){
                   var file = $scope.myFile;
                   
                   console.log('file is ' );
                   console.dir(file);
                   
                   var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
                   fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
                };
             }]);
```

```html
     
          <div ng-app = "myApp" ng-controller = "myCtrl">
             <input type = "file" file-model = "myFile"/>
             <button ng-click = "uploadFile()">upload me</button>
          </div>
```

This would do for the client side. Now for the server side, you need to write a script that can handle the uploaded image correctly and place it on the destination where you intend to..

[This piece from the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php) discusses the PUT method and file uploads (multipart/form-data).

I can't quote any parts from it because I think everything is important. You should read it in detail but to summarize it's not possible without changes to your Apache configuration and creation of auxiliary scripts.

With Laravel you should use [Form Method Spoofing][2] (basically a variable called `_method`) and keep on using POST. The `_method` will allow you to call Laravel's PUT action correctly.